# How to bringtofront a messagebox in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Just need a little help with a Powershell Script.

I have a last messagebox on my script. what i want to accomplish is bring the messagebox in front of all the windows.

cmdlet that i use is

$end=[system.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show('StartUP Tool Progress Completed!','StartUP Warning')

Comment: try ShowDialog and not show

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Powershell how do I bring a messagebox to the foreground, and change focus to a button in the message box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299433/in-powershell-how-do-i-bring-a-messagebox-to-the-foreground-and-change-focus-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, if all you need is a message box you can use the Wscript Shell:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("StartUP Tool Progress Completed",0,"Completed",0x0)
```

For more information: [Popup Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Thank you Kirss Milne, This has  perfectly worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a WinForms question, more than a PowerShell question. You'll need to pass in Form.ActiveForm. Form.ActiveForm would give you the currently active form, even if you are raising your MessageBox from any other class.

However, I think you might want to look at `Read-Host -AsSecureString` or, more preferably, `Get-Credential` if the prompt is for confidential data.

`Read-Host` uncontrollably stops the script to prompt the user, which means that you can never have another script that includes the script that uses `Read-Host`.

Thankfully, PowerShell has a lot of built-in help for launching dialogs. You're trying to ask for parameters.

You should use the

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
```

attribute, and correct typing, to ask for the parameters. Read up on "params" if you haven't already.

If you use Parameter attribute on a `[SecureString]`, it will prompt for a password field. If you use this on a Credential type, (`[Management.Automation.PSCredential]`), the credentials dialog will pop up, if the parameter isn't there. A string will just become a plain old text box. If you add a HelpMessage to the parameter attribute (that is, `[Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = 'New User Credentials')]`) then it will become help text for the prompt.

Finally, you can try this *dirty* trick, leveraging Microsoft Visual basic DLLs:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null

$computer = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter a computer name", "Computer", "$env:computername")
```